# Reading from a serial interface

Tags: linux, tty, cat, serial-port

I have a serial device running which I need to read data from(I have absolutely no control over the device itself) except reading its output; using hyper terminal in Windows I am able to detect a meaningful traffic and yesterday when I used cat (or my own little C program to read the data and print it to stdout) it worked fine.

Today, when I use cat/my program all I get is a sort-of corrupted data, yet hyper terminal still shows the data.

What could possibly be wrong? how could it have worked yesterday but not today?

The file I am/was reading is `/dev/ttyUSB1`

*Please note that I am never running BOTH my program and cat, only one of them at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone on SO hinted in the right direction; the problem was with the baudrate, it was set to a different value than what I need.

To check the baudrate:
`stty -F /dev/ttyUSB1`
To set the baudrate:
`stty -F /dev/ttyUSB1 57600` (57600 in my case is the baudrate my device needs)

It's working like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

Serial ports are especially weird beasts.  You'll want to use an Old School terminal emulation program.  I used to think `tip` was the best, but nobody seems to have the source for it any more. `cu` comes with UUCP, and it's a complete hassle to install and configure, don't even bother.

A quick google around tells me that people tend to use [minicom](http://alioth.debian.org/projects/minicom/) these days. [Here's a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347962/how-to-connect-to-a-terminal-to-serial-usb-device-on-ubuntu-10-10) that seems like it has some bearing, at least on using `minicom` to talk to a USB serial device.

Let us know how this turns out. Update your question or leave a comment or something.

Comment: Solved, someone on SO hinted in the right direction; please see my answer